set an auto timestamp as a build number for Xcode cloud
I know that I can control the initial build number manually from appstoreconnect. and this number will be incremented by a scale of 1 every time a new build job is triggered.
I want to set the build number as a timestamp in the following format YYMMDDhhmm. This format will allow less manual maintenance for the build number as I am building and releasing to appstoreconnect from multiple sources and this format will resolve the issue of build numbers colliding or not following the right sequencing.
is there any chance something like this is possible?
I searched to see if I can add variables to the manual build number field but no.
